# Paypal: Subtotal and Purchase Total mismatch

Tags: paypal

we have an ecommerce website, which offers checkout with paypal option. The shipping charges are added to the price of the purchase and then the customer may choose paypal option. However, on paypal the purchase total is not the subtotal but rather the price (of the product) which in turn is (subtotal - shipping charges). How to settle it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHXFb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal transaction will process with the information sent from your ecommerce website when it sets up the transaction.

If you want the transaction to process for different amounts, your website needs to send different amounts.

A programmer or administrator familiar with your website's ecommerce software will need to make the appropriate adjustments for you.